Load some tabs at startup but not all
I'd like firefox to remeber all open tabs between sessions, but to only load some at startup (specifically the messaging webapps).
I know there is an option to keep them all unloaded, and to auto load the pinned ones; but I'm looking for a tab-by-tab control. If firefox does not allow that, is there an extension for it?
